# Blockchain Api v2

Tags: wallet, api, blockchain.info

I'm new to this api. In the new blockchain.info api, there is a local service running and we can create wallets. But how to use this api to check balance and make payments using existing blockchain.info wallet.
Thanks.

Comment: You should edit the title of your question to *be* the question, rather than the topic.  It would help attract answers, and make both the question and answer more searchable for the future.

Answer (score 1):

api v1

https://blockchain.info/pl/merchant/'.$login.'/new_address?password='.$haslo.'&api_code="myapi"&label='.$id, false, $timeout

how to do it correctly on API v2?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the local service running, you check your balance and send payments by making http requests to it.

If you started the service on localhost:5000, for example, to check your balance you make an http request to:

```
http://localhost:5000/merchant/:your_guid/balance?password=your_password&api_code=your_api_code
```

You can make these http requests using an http library and the language of your choice, or using one of Blockchain.info's api libraries.